# Was Zink ever valid spelling for Zinc?

Tags: british-english, orthography, australian-english, nineteenth-century-english

On the Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange I asked [What might 'pitt Zink' in 1873 South Australian diary mean?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13140) and the first answer I received more or less aligns with my thinking that Zink is being used where today we would (in Australia) write Zinc.  The writer was living in South Australia, but prior to emigrating had been a school master in Staffordshire, England for at least the period 1821-1827.

Was Zink ever considered to be a valid spelling of Zinc and, if so, when might it have ceased to be used?

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zink) lists "zink" as a "misspelling of Zinc, a metallic chemical element." The German spelling is *zink*. Googling "zinc etymology" shows that the spelling seems to have changed in the mid-1600s.

Comment: Bear in mind that there was no "authority" for correct English spelling prior to the first reputable dictionaries.  The first reasonably credible English dictionary was produced in 1604, and Samuel Johnson's work -- arguably the first "modern" dictionary - came out in 1755.  The OED was not complete until 1927.  And it's reasonable that a variant spelling could remain in common use for around 100 years after the "official" spelling was blessed by Johnson or OED or whoever.

Comment: "I have guided mine destiny vary vell so far, and I zink I can still so do." J. Storer Clouston: *Count Bunker*.

Comment: My understanding is that the word *sink* (as in "kitchen sink") derives from zinc. The fact that it ends with a 'k' implies to me that the metal would have ended with a 'k' as well at some point in time.

Comment: @simba Old English [Sincan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Sink) looks like the source of *sink,* not *zinc.*

Comment: @jejorda2 fair enough; I didn't look it up; that's just what I'd been told in the past and it seemed logical enough that I accepted it.

Comment: @simba that doesn't seem very likely. Phrases like "sink hole" meaning a natural hole in the ground which water drains into have nothing to do with metal.

Comment: Apropos of nothing in particular, the work "zink" has been imported into English from German as the name of a type of medieval musical instrument, with the original English name of "cornett" (with two t's, and not the same instrument as the modern cornet used in marching bands etc). But the Aussie miners probably didn't know that!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to *Oxford English Dictionary*, the answer is yes.  ***Zinke*** was the earliest attested spelling of the word, with ***zink*** also preceding ***zinc***.

The earliest attested use of the word is from **1651.**

> Any sulphurous, and imperfect metall, as Iron, Copper, or **Zinke**.

- John French · *The art of distillation; or, A treatise of the choisest spagyricall preparations* · 1st edition, 1651 (1 vol.).

The spelling you suggested is believed from **1734.**

> We took six Ounces of Copper, and melting it in a Wind-Furnance, added to it an Ounce of **Zink.**

- Peter Shaw · *Chemical Lectures publickly read at London in … 1731, and 1732; and since at Scarborough, in 1733, for the improvement of arts, trades, and natural philosophy* · 1734.

And finally, the earliest attested spelling with a 'c' is from **1813**

> **Zinc** is one of the most combustible of the common metals.

- Humphry Davy · *Elements of agricultural chemistry, in a course of lectures of the Board of Agriculture*

---

### You ask: *When might it have ceased to be used?*

OED indicates that ***zink*** was used into the 1800's, in its remarks on the forms of the word:

> Forms:  16–18 zink, (16 zinke, 16–17 zinck), 17– zinc.

However, jlovegren proved that some uses from the 1900's can be found.  I would add to that these snippets from **1906** and **1914**, respectively.  However, the dates provided by OED are probably an accurate measure of when each form was in *common* use.

[image]

- [The Monroeville Breeze (Monroeville, Indiana)11 Jan 1906, Thu](https://www.newspapers.com/image/36019488/?terms=zink)

[image]

- [The Lima News (Lima, Ohio)15 Jan 1914, Thu](https://www.newspapers.com/image/37603578/?terms=zink)

Comment: Earliest attested spelling with a c is from 1813, but “17– zinc”? That looks a bit odd…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was wondering about that too.  My guess is it's just the first use they attested that starts with a 'c', maybe not necessarily the earliest such spelling they could find. I'm not sure how they get their dating on the various forms.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "17-" just means "from the 17th century to the present time.

Comment: @alephzero I think what Janus was confused about was why the date of the earliest attestation for "zinc" is 1813.  17- means "1700 - present" (not 17th century). http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/  So the question is, why is there no attestation of "zinc" from the 1700's?  Since it's not the *first* attested date of the word generally, I'm guessing they don't necessarily try to antedate every spelling form.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the spelling in print sometimes, though obviously it's not standard. May be influence from German, Dutch, Danish, etc.

See below from American Machinist, Volume 27, Issues 27-52 (1904).

[image]

And this from an 1822 work, *A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary, and Expositor of the English Language...*.

[image]